# MAMP for Mac version 3.4 mysql general query log not working

Tags: mysql, mamp

This is not a duplicate of another question. I really like MAMP as it simplifies development and am just trying to figure out how to enable general query log.

I am trying to enable the general query log in MAMP 3.4 for mac

What I have tried

1. create file /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_sql.log
2. chmod 777 /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_sql.log
3. add the following by editing template my.cnf to the mysql section

   general_log = 1
   log = /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_sql.log
4. Restart mysql

When I run queries I do not get anything written to that file.

Am I missing a step? My other changes such as mode take affect; just not this log.

Comment: Hi Chris - this is either off-topic due to using a development tool in production or off-topic due to you asking about how to configure a development tool. Please see the above-linked duplicate question for more info on why you shouldn't use these one-click stack installers.

Comment: I got it working by restarting mysql